# Anonymous Type Collection

Tags: vb.net, anonymous-types

How would you solve this? I want to return this collection:

```
Public Function GetShippingMethodsByCarrier(ByVal Carrier As ShippingCarrier) As List(of ?)

    Return Carrier.ShippingMethods.Select(Function(x) New With {.ID = x.ID, .Name = String.Format("{0} {1}", Carrier.Name, x.Description)})


End Function
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return an anonymous type from a function like this because it has no name.

Since this is a public function is should have a well defined return type. Create a new class holding those two properties.

Its possible to return it if the return type is an inferred generic parameter, but that's not what you want here. This is useful for LINQ where an anonymous type essentially gets passed through from a parameter to the result type, but not useful for what you're doing.

You could also use a Tuple, but then you'd lose the property names. And it wouldn't be extensible since adding a new property would break caller code. So I wouldn't recommend that either.

Comment: So you would have to make a class to hold those two properties and return a list of those?

Comment: @Sam I'd recommend doing that. There are workarounds, but I wouldn't recommend them here.

Comment: So why does this not work? `code` Dim q = From c In db.Customers
                    Where c.ID = 4
                    Select New With {Key .ID = c.ID, Key .Locations = c.CustomerLocations, .Orders = c.SalesOrders, .SalesRep = c.SalesRepresentative}

            For Each l In q.locations

            Next

Comment: @Sam how about editing your new attempt into the question? What you posted in the comment is unformatted and might not be complete.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is you're attempting to return an anonymous type in a strongly typed manner.  This is just not possible in VB.Net (or C# for that matter).  Anonymous types are meant to be anonymous and their names cannot be stated explicitly in code.  The two ways to work around this are to

Option #1 Use / Create a strongly named type like the following

```
Structure Item
  Public ID as Integer
  Public Name As String
  Public Description As String
End Structure
```

Option #2 Set the return type to be `Object` and access the list in a late bound manner

**EDIT**

As CodeInChaos it is possible to return them in a strongly type manner in a generic context.  But that doesn't appear to help you for this particular problem.

Comment: It is possible to return a strongly types anonymous type from a function using generic inference. It's just not useful for the OPs problem.